# ORACLE APEX: Try to insert LOGIN PAGE custom email to a table

Tags: oracle, input, oracle-apex

I try to create a different action when user presses the LOGIN button.
I can't insert values from the LOGIN form.

I Try with this code:

```
INSERT INTO DEBTOR_EMAIL VALUES (V':P9999_USERNAME', V':P9999_EMAIL');
```

And I get an error:

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 30: ORA-00936: missing expression

Could some please help how to reference form input fields?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `v` and single quotes:

```
INSERT INTO DEBTOR_EMAIL VALUES (:P9999_USERNAME, :P9999_EMAIL);
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/html/E39147_04/bldapp_item.htm#CEGGIDGB says. And which section should I put this code. Under Login button I have tryed "Server Side Condition" and SQL Expression, but it still gives me an error. Could you please help to choose where to put it? Probably I should create a Dynamic action

Comment: Create a **process** which contains code I wrote; let it fire when the LOGIN button is pressed. Also, create a **branch** which will take you to next page in your application (the one that opens if login is successful).

Comment: My process name is Log email (Under standard LOG IN processes). In the right side panel, under the "Source" section I have choosen "Local Database". My PL/SQL Code is: "BEGIN
INSERT INTO DEBTOR_EMAIL VALUES (:P9999_USERNAME, :P9999_EMAIL);
END;" And it does not give me an error, but it fills the DEBTOR_EMAIL table with ('-','-') values :( I don't know why. My "execute options" in the right side panel are: RUn process: "Once per session or  When reset". Could You please help what am I doing wrong? Because It does not give me back my success message or either Error message

Comment: Custom login process should invoke your login procedure which checks whether user should be allowed to access the application. I suggest you to create another process which inserts a row into the table and runs when LOGIN button is pressed (set it in "Server side conditions"). I don't know what "-" represents; it isn't username nor email. Did you correctly spell those item names? Is it page 9999? What happens if you substitute `:P9999_USERNAME` with `:APP_USER`?

Comment: :APP_USER works well! Thanks! But now, it inserts a row with :APP_USER which is in my case '1' and insert the '-' character in the filled out email.

Comment: As I said, I don't know what "-" is. Does your client, perhaps, displays NULL values as "-"? If so, does e-mail value exists in P9999_EMAIL item (i.e. in session state)? That's usually done by submitting the page which means that LOGIN button should submit. Does it do that?

Comment: P9999_EMAIL is my input field, I've created it. Does it have a short variable name, like :APP_USER, or how can I reference it? Because it seems that :P9999_EMAIL is a blind variable and that's why it isnerts '-' character

Comment: No, there's nothing "short" for it. Enable debugging, run the page in debug mode and check session state for those items. If you can't see anything, then - once again - submit.

Answer (score 0):

While the answer above is completely correct and does answer the actual question, I don't think this is the best way to handle this problem. With this solution, you have locked that functionality in the login page. In *most* cases, the application login is handled outside of apex (single sign on, social authentication, etc).  Adding code in the login screen is not possible in those cases.
A more robust solution is to create an application process with a processing point "After Authentication" and perform the insert statement there.